# Is it possible to change yum's timeout regarding to yum install?

Tags: yum

We have 30+ Linux machines in a cluster and all machines are using a local repo server to download rpm pagkages.

Even if we are using a local repository, we found that network issue can occur. E.g. yum installation problems, because of slow network in our network.

So my question is - can we define a custom timeout in `/etc/yum.conf` in order to tell yum to continue installation and not to fail during installation?

What I've found until now - from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories

> `retries=value`
>
> where `value` is an integer 0 or greater. This value sets the number of times yum should attempt to retrieve a file before returning an error. Setting this to 0 makes yum retry forever. The default value is 10.

Other suggestion is:

```
[main]
timeout=60
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `man yum.conf`, there is this option:

> timeout: Number of seconds to wait for a connection before timing out. Defaults to 30 seconds. This may be too short of a time for extremely overloaded sites.

According to the documentation, you can set `timeout` in either the `[main]` section of `yum.conf` to apply globally or the `[repositories]` section to set per repository.

The default location of `yum.conf` is `/etc/yum.conf`.

Comment: see my update , do you mean according to my update we need to append timeout=60 , and its enough ?

Comment: I do not know if 60 seconds will be enough for your use case, but that would be how you adjust the `yum` timeout.

Comment: Whoever needs that inside Dockerfile, I used `RUN echo "[main]" >> /etc/yum.conf && echo "timeout=60" >> /etc/yum.conf`

Comment: Whoever needs that inside Dockerfile, I used `RUN sed -i "s|timeout=30|timeout=300 |g" /etc/yum.conf` to update the value in the config file